# Selectively Import Objective C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have class X, which is an Objective-C object. I'm wanting to ONLY import X into Y.swift and not Z.swift. As I see right now, the bridging header makes all imported code accessible in every class, and I don't want that.

Is this even possible?

Comment: No that's not possible, unless there's any undocumented way of doing that. It's an all or none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can. Create a framework of  class `X`, then import it only in `Y.swift`

```
import FrameworkX
```

While the bridging header is module wide, `import` is file local.